# exporting mysql using php is blocked by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am using the below php code to export from my mysql database:

```
 <?php

require_once('connect.php');

$group = 1;//$_GET['group'];

$export = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM relationship WHERE group_id = $group");

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_desired_name.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";

mysql_close($my_connection);

?>
```

I can download the file from my browser (chrome) if I simply run this php file.

However, the download does not show if I use a click button on another page and call below javascript to run this php file:

```
<script>
function export_data()
{alert(1);
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "export.php",     
        data: {group: localStorage.group_id},        
        dataType: "html",           
        success: function(response){

            alert(response);

        }

    });alert(2);
}
</script>
```

Javascript will alert all the xls contents, but block the download.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use `window.location` instead of AJAX ?

```
<script>
function export_data()
{
window.location='export.php';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove JavaScript click even and direct create a link

```
<a href="export.php"> Download </a>
```

This will download file without referencing page on browser.